# Transcendental Galois Theory

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, galois-theory, algebraic-groups

> Is there a good reference on transcendental Galois Theory?

More precisely, if $K/k$ admits a separating transcendence basis (or maybe if it is a separably generated extension) it seems to me that many of the usual theorems of Galois theory go through.  Moreover, the group $\text{Aut}(K/k)$ seems to have additional structure; namely it should be an algebraic group over $k$.

For example, it seems to me that $k(x_1, ..., x_n)/k$ has automorphism group $GL_n(k)$.  (EDIT:  As Qiaochu Yuan points out, this is incorrect; the automorphism group at least must contain $PGL_{n+1}(k)$, acting via its action on the function field of $\mathbb{P}_k^n$.)  This sort of thing must be well-studied; if so, what are the standard references on the subject?

I have seen Pete L. Clark's excellent (rough) notes on related subjects [here](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/transgal.pdf) but they seem not to address quite these sorts of questions.

Comment: Isn't the automorphism group more something like $\text{PGL}_{n+1}(k)$?

Comment: How do you figure?  I could just be being silly but I don't even see an action of $PGL_{n+1}$...

Comment: I think the action is by generalized fractional linear transformations, e.g. when $n = 1$ we can send $x_1$ to any $\frac{ax_1 + b}{cx_1 + d}$ and this has inverse the corresponding inverse fractional linear transformation.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're right; as I've remarked in my edit, this action should arise via the natural action of $PGL_{n+1}$ on the function field of $\mathbb{P}^n_k$.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For every $n \geq 1$, there is a natural effective action of $\operatorname{PGL}_{n+1}(k)$ on $k(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$.  In fact $\operatorname{PGL}_{n+1}(k)$ is the automorphism group of $\mathbb{P}^n_{/k}$, the action being the obvious one induced by the action of $\operatorname{GL}_{n+1}(k)$ on the vector space $k^{n+1}$ in which $\mathbb{P}^n$ is the set of lines.

However, no one said this was the entire automorphism group of $k(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$!  It is when $n = 1$ -- for instance because every rational map from a smooth curve to a projective variety is a morphism ("valuative criterion for properness").  However, $\operatorname{PGL}_{n+1}(k)$ is known **not** to be the entire automorphism group of $k(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ when $n > 1$.  Rather, the full automorphism group is called the [Cremona group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cremona_group).  For $n = 2$ we have a problem in the geometry of surfaces, and it was shown (by Max Noether when $k = \mathbb{C}$) that the automorphism group here is generated by the linear automorphisms described above together with a certain set of simple, well-understood birational maps, called **quadratic maps** or indeed **Cremona transformations**.  But even when $n = 2$ this automorphism group is not an algebraic group: it's bigger than that.

When $n \geq 3$ it is further known that the linear automorphisms and the Cremona transformations do not generate the whole automorphism group, and apparently no one has even a decent guess as to what a set of generators might look like.  I had the good fortune of hearing a talk by James McKernan on (in part) this subject within the last few months, so I am a bit more up on this than I otherwise would be.  Anyway, he gave us the sense that this is a pretty hopeless problem at present.  For instance, see [this recent preprint](https://arxiv.org/PS_cache/arxiv/pdf/0909/0909.3302v5.pdf) in which a rather eminent algebraic geometer works rather hard to prove a seemingly rather weak result about finite subgroups of the three dimensional Cremona group!

So, yes, this is a different sort of question from the ones considered in my [rough note](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/transgal.pdf) on transcendental Galois theory.  To all appearances it's a much harder question...

Comment: Thanks!  I should have realized that we could allow birational automorphisms of $\mathbb{P}^n$ as well; I wonder if there is some way of functorially identifying an algebraic subgroup (e.g. look at automorphisms that fix some basepoint on $\mathbb{P}^n$...).

Comment: Recently I have started updating links containing `www.math.uga.edu` (which is no longer working) to `math.uga.edu`. I do not know whether this edit is substantive enough for the author of the post to receive the notification - if yes, I apologize for lost of pings. But I should be able to finish this in a few installments. Anyway, here I changed it not to http://math.uga.edu/~pete/galois.pdf - instead I have used http://math.uga.edu/~pete/transgalois.pdf (I suppose that was the intention of giving the "redirect pdf" there.)